How to throttle MacBook M3 so a browser-based game runs at normal speed?
Now and then I love to play a game on the internet archive, specially for the Mac. It's a 1986 game (Dark Castle) and runs beautiful in my browser. With my previous 2014 Intel MacBook it ran on a comparable speed I'm used to from my childhood memories.
The other day I've bought the top-of-the-line 2024 MacBook M3, which is a beast. It's even such a beast that the internet version of Dark Castle is unplayable because it runs too fast.
I just found this question, but that only works for Intel chips.
Is it possible to slow down or throttle my Mac before starting this game and enjoy the game at the original speed it ran in 1986?

Such a great game. I wonder if app tamer could run the browser on efficiency cores only?
